# Why does the default constructor always appear in javadoc documentation, even though it is not present in the code?

Tags: java, javadoc

Why does the default constructor always appear in javadoc documentation, even though it is not present in the code?

One possible remedy is to explicitly write the default constructor, even though I don't need it, and just add comment to it "For internal use only" or something like that...

Thanks

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#defaultconstructors

Comment: @ZouZou Can you please reply with this, I will accept it as answer.

Comment: If it's 'for internal use only' it should be protected or private or package-protected. The Javadoc tool is helping you here. I don't see any reason to object to it.

Comment: @EJP I do agree, but for whatever reason the project I work on has lots of stuff as public or protected even though they should be private.

Comment: If they are public they should be documented. You can't expect `Javadoc` to read your mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html:

```
The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors
```

That means, that the default constructor will be added implicitly in a compile time. At the time, when it gets for javadoc, it is already added.
This is specified here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#defaultconstructors:

```
Section 8.8.7 of the Java Language Specification, Second Edition describes a default constructor: If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor that takes no parameters is automatically provided. It invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments. The constructor has the same access as its class.
The Javadoc tool generates documentation for default constructors. When it documents such a constructor, Javadoc leaves its description blank, because a default constructor can have no doc comment.
```

Comment: It is bit strange why they did it that way, but oh well :) I will accept this as answer in few minutes, there is a time limit :(

Comment: I`m not sure. Maybe it generates based on the compiled code. In this case, there is no difference if it is implicitly added or not.